# Android button's weight inside the RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to have a weight for button inside the RelativeLayout like LinearLayout? 
Or any way to make It possible?

[image: Portrait]

[image: LandScape]

Here's my LayoutCode

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
                android:text="Button" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

If I change my 2 RelativeLayouts (The Left and Right) this will be the output

[image]

Comment: layout_weight does not work for relative layout. Use Linear Layout instead...

Comment: If I change it to linearlayout the 3rd relativelayout sticks to the 2nd layout, I want the 3rd layout stick to right not in the 2nd layout

Comment: what exactly you want? image-3 or image-2?

Comment: what exactly do u want to do?? Show all buttons and make up the rest of the space to the Textview??

Comment: @Renjith , Yep, I have solved the problem

Comment: if u solved it, mark it as answer...

Comment: I'm sorry my explanation is complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing, put all your RelativeLayouts inside a LinearLayout. Now assign weights to the RelativeLayouts according to the size they are supposed to occupy. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Renjith's suggestion

Sorry for my complex explanation, but here is my code and the output.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button08"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button07"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <Button
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

For the buttons you want to align to the right, if you are using a RelativeLayout you can use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

to align the buttons with the parent RelativeLayout